# Let's add the link to "question close stats" in all the sections of the "/tools" page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, 10k-tools

The [`/tools`](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) page available to [10K users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) contains a section `links` with the following ones:

- information about moderation tools
- new answers to old questions
- suggested edit stats
- site analytics
- protected questions

However, when loading the `close` tab, yet another link shows in that section:

- question close stats

This is not consistent, since the rest of the links still show in all tabs (specially *suggested edit stats*, of the same kind). To me, seeing a `links` section makes me think that is always the same and [just now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339402/1983854) I discovered this helpful stats page. That is, the difference on the text is not obvious and seeing the change from 5 to 6 links is rare, hence the text remains unnoticed.

Could you add the link to *question close stats* to all the tabs within the `/tools` page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the latest build, the links at the bottom of the 10k tools pages should be consistent. They should all be:

- information about moderation tools
- new answers to old questions
- suggested edit stats
- site analytics
- question close stats
- protected questions

Thanks to [Konamiman](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/136880/konamiman) for getting this done.